# Window app crashes

Tags: c#, windows, entity-framework-4, publishing

Using one click publishing(VS2010) I publish my windows app.  Its a pretty simple application that uses only one 3rd party library: EntityFramework.  When it installs and runs it gens the following error in the event log:

```
Application: HNITPrinterMgtApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Data.EntityException
Stack:
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean,     System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.String, System.String, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetResults(System.Nullable`1<System.Data.Objects.MergeOption>)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at HNITPrinterMgtApp.Classes.UiPresenter.GetCurrentListOfPrinters()
   at HNITPrinterMgtApp.HNITPrinter.SetFormForTypeOfUser()
   at HNITPrinterMgtApp.HNITPrinter.DetermineTypeOfUser()
   at HNITPrinterMgtApp.HNITPrinter..ctor()
   at HNITPrinterMgtApp.Program.Main()
```

All the dll's are there that need to be... Not quite sure what I am missing... or what else I need to do....

If I am using EF with my windows app... should I use a different method of distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note with EF you need to have the connections strings in your main app.config I know that from using my own class libraries that use EF.  Also Possibly check to make sure integrated security is not being used or that the user has access to the database.

Comment: the connection string is in the main app.config.  No problem there... feels like there is another step... just cant pin it down.  First windows app deployment in a long time.  I have been doing mainly web apps...

Comment: Another thing would be to make sure its not integrated security or that the user has access to connect to the database.

Comment: at Bear, yeah I dont like using logins and didnt realize that the db was not setup with appropriate permissions... :p

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a permissions issue.  Everything works fine!

Comment: Excellent glad the solution was found! I have edited my post as well to contain the solution so folks searching with the same issue will find it faster.